# Any downside to using `sudo git` to upload `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and `/etc/nginx/ssl/` config files on github?

Tags: nginx, git, sudo, root, configuration-management

I'm contemplating uploading config files from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and `/etc/nginx/ssl` to a private Github repository.

Doing so would require me to use `git` with `sudo` (or from `root` user) for the `ssl` folder at least (which can only be read by root because it also contains SSL keys).

Are there any downsides or (security) risks in doing so? (OS is Ubuntu 18.04)

I would most probably limit the files in the repository to `.conf` files to avoid any SSL private keys being uploaded.

Comment: why you don't use a configuration?

Comment: what do you mean? I have specific `.conf` files in `sites-available` that I want to backup and keep track of via git. But this requires using git with `sudo` because files in `/etc/nginx/` are owned by `root`

Comment: In order to commit a file into a local repository: 1. the file must be readable by the user doing the commit, 2. the repository (`.git`) directory must be writable by the user. So you don't need to be root as long as you don't want to commit files, which are not readable by a normal user.

Comment: Thanks - files in `sites-available` actually seem to be readable by normal user so git without sudo would work. However location `\etc\nginx\ssl` (forgot to mention this one) that contains both encryption keys and config files (configs that I'd like to save to github) are only readable by `root`

Comment: @Jean Monet ansible, puppet intend of having configuration files directly in git

Comment: @c4f4t0r I haven't yet gotten my head around ansible. Can legitimately assume having config files in git is best practice?

Comment: @Jean Monet in git I store the puppet code or ansible code that generate the configuration, I don't think is a good idea to have a raw configurations files in git